# Double Tab separator in Dataweave Mule

Tags: csv, mule, mule-studio, dataweave

How to give double tab space as separator in Dataweave  i have tried the option '\t\t'. But it didn't work. Please suggest the answer.

I have tried like

```
  %output application/csv separator='\t\t'
```

Comment: Can someone let me know why dataweave is accepting only one character as separator. Can we acheive this double tabspace as separator in dataweave. In datamapper it is acheivable, cant we acheive this in dataweave??

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try with this expression `%output application/csv separator='\\t'` . I think this will work.

Comment: I have tried this option. It doesnt work. Getting o/p in the below way
12345\\gender\\male


Which is incorrect. Have you implemented and is it working for you??

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know that isn't possible at the moment, only one separation character can be used.

As a workaround you could use:
%output application/csv separator=" "

And concat extra WHITESPACES after your values (no tabs)

value: myValue ++ "   ",
etc...

Comment: I have tried the above. I got the following exception.

********************************************************************************
Message               : String index out of range: 0 (java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException). Message payload is of type: WeaveMessageProcessor$WeaveOutputHandler
Type                  : org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
Payload               : com.mulesoft.weave.mule.WeaveMessageProcessor$WeaveOutputHandler@1c6df0d

Comment: please post your complete DataWeave script, and the input you are testing with, then i can point out the issue maybe

Answer (score 0):

Separator is specified as reader property in the Mule XML configuration file, so you need to specify the separator character for CSV files as an XML escaped Unicode character `(&#009;)`.

In Dataweave can you try using

```
<dw:input-payload>
<dw:reader-property name="separator" value="&#009;"/>
</dw:input-payload>
```

Here is the link, hope this help :-
https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/ka434000000TR2IAAW/How-to-use-a-TAB-character-as-the-CSV-separator-for-input-in-DataWeave